# HTML5 accessibility testing?

Tags: html, accessibility

For all the HTML5 how great it is for accessibility readers/devices hype, I haven't even seen one of these readers/devices yet that works with HTML5.  After I create an HTML5 webpage, where do I go to test it?  I'd like to hear what it sounds like in an accessibility reader.

I know the Text To Speech on a Mac has no idea about HTML5.  That is like most text to speech software unfortunately.

Comment: damn, that's a good question, so "+1". But if you didn't have such a reputation I would sugget to close it as off-topic though as "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". But with such a reputation you probably know better than me what you're doing...

Comment: Thanks @Bartdude.  Yes - a little off topic.  The problem is that you just can't find anything out there on this.  So, hopefully other developers using HTML5 will have some suggestions.

Comment: HTML5 is HTML. What particular features of HTML5, specifically, are you talking about? The new sectioning elements? HTML5 video? Something else? Please expand.

Comment: Are you talking about specific "accessibility readers/devices", or screen readers only? And what do you mean by testing? Using the tools for yourself or some automatic tests looking for errors/problems? How do you know that "Text To Speech" has no idea about HTML5, i.e., what happens and what should happen instead?

Answer (score 1):

One of the tools we use in our corporate environment is [NVDA](http://www.nvaccess.org/). It's a great tool and freely available.

[JAWS](http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) is one program that is popular with corporate clients, but it is very expensive. Older versions predated the ARIA standards and it took a few versions for those features to become supported so your results will definitely vary by version.

This question is kind of objective. Screen readers treat things differently and people are typically slow to upgrade to new versions that are more supportive of the ARIA standards. The main reason why people are slow to upgrade is due to the cost (primarily JAWS and ZoomText).

Typically, the way we go abut testing these things is with a combination of keyboard testing and screen reader verification. If you can get through the application with a keyboard and the screen reader reads all of the cues it needs to be able to understand what is going on without being able to see the content, you are in pretty good shape.

Comment: Wow - I wonder than out of the non developer community, who is actually using accessibility readers?  Meaning, those that actually need this type of software, where do they go?  No one is certainly making it easy for them to find the software they need. I should dig deeper into my Mac because it seems it should have something specially that can read HTML5.

Comment: Interesting grid showing how some HTML5 tags are supported by readers while others aren't: http://tink.co.uk/2013/02/screen-reader-support-for-html5-sections/. Guess it is no different then the coding browser compatibility issues developers have to wrestle with.

Comment: In my experience, even the supposed accessibility experts related to this area are glorified testers that are more familiar with the tools than being able to understand the underlying issues and how to fix them.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell not sure why you say that. For example, among others, both [Steve Faulkner](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/author/admin/) and [Gez Lemon](http://juicystudio.com) are members of the HTML5 Working Group and prominent a11y authors and advocates.

Comment: My comment was anecdotal related to the people I have worked with in the corporate sector.

Comment: **VoiceOver** both on OS X and iOS is the screen reader of choice in the Apple world. Developed by Apple, already installed, decent support of HTML5 (even browsers "don't support HTML5", just part of it. Especially since HTML5 isn't "finished" and not a W3C Recommendation yet ^^)

Comment: OP: blind people and partially sighted people learn about Assistive Technologies through schools, educators (if blind at birth for example, and will also learn Braille). If it's a condition that happens to them while already adults, well they'll see doctors prior to that, social services and specialized associations. And friends, family, etc Edit: in developed and rich countries at least. I don't know for other countries.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of levels to this.

## Browsers

The first level is the browsers, how well do they map the HTMl5 elements to the accessibility API? Steve Faulkner of The Paciello Group maintains a website that has a good amount of information about [HTML5 Accessiblity](http://www.html5accessibility.com).

Firefox, pretty good. Others, ok in places. It does depend what you mean by support though. For example, what should a screen reader do with `<section>`? Probably nothing, but it doesn't freak out, so is that a problem?

### Assistive Technology

The second level is then how various assistive technologies support HTML5 elements. 4thspace linked to some testing of [screenreader support of HTML5 section elements](http://tink.co.uk/2013/02/screen-reader-support-for-html5-sections/), but overall [WAI-ARIA support is much better](http://www.slideshare.net/stevefaulkner/html5-accessibility-is-it-ready-yet).

Looking beyond screen readers: Screen magnifiers don't do anything in particular with HTML5, nor does Dragon (voice recognition), so be careful what you rely on. For example, Dragon doesn't recognise HTML elements you make into interactive elements that are not natively interactive (e.g. buttons/links work but a `<div>` scripted as a button does not).

HTMl5 tends to encompass anything in the modern web-stack, so a more specific question would be needed for more.